# How to change Font Family using setState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to change my `Text` Widget font family on button click.

Which means I created a `Container` and in this `Container` I added multiple text style widget with `GestureDetector` widget. So whenever I click on Particular font family, I want to change my `Text` widget Font-Family.

Any suggestion for doing this type of functionality.

Comment: what you want to do is change the style of the text when the button is pressed.
Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904495/how-to-change-a-text-style-on-flutter-when-button-pressed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a text style on Flutter when button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904495/how-to-change-a-text-style-on-flutter-when-button-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to store font name

reference it in your `text` Widget

then call `setState` to update the value of variable and UI

```
String fontName;

//your TextWidget
Text("some text for testing",
     style: TextStyle( fontFamily: fontName )
)

//function to update the value
_updateFont(String name){
  setState((){
    fontName = name;
  });
}
```

make sure you are importing the fonts to be used
add them in `pubspec.yaml` file under `fonts`

```
- family: font1
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/font1.ttf
```

Comment: I have list of font family, but I want to change when I click on any particular font family `container`  `Text` font family should change.  @Vicky Salunkhe

Comment: yeah, I know did you try the code?  just use the `text` widget inside your `container` widget and call the function when you want the font to be updated

Comment: hi @JaiminBhikadiya if possible upvote the answer too

Answer (score 2):

Hope this works or modify accordingly:

code inside your Text Widget:

```
Text("Your Text",
              style: tapped
              ?TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Your-Font-Family')
              :TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Your-Second-Font-Family'),
              ),
```

code inside Gesture Detector:

```
 GestureDetector(
              child: your child widget,
              onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                tapped = !tapped;
              });
            }),
```

and remember to define `bool tapped;` in your widget class.

Still, if you face any difficulty, add the code to comment so I can help you out.

Comment: I have List of font family so is it possible when I applied above mentioned code? @Adithya Shetty

Comment: Using my method you can only toggle between two font families for a text.