# Change color and icon with provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget which contains a container where I've described it's color which has an icon.
How do we change color of the container and icon in it with provider?

```
Container(
      child: Icon(Icons.trash,
        size: 27,
      ),
      color: Colors.green[500],
    ),
```

Here I have radio buttons where the title in name of colour I want in the container

```
RadioListTile(
title: Text('red'),
),
RadioListTile(
title: Text('green[500]'),
),
RadioListTile(
title: Text('blue'),
)
```

when the user clicks on these tiles, I want color of container to change accordingly with icons.

My actual code.

```
background: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, right: 380, bottom: 5),
      child: Icon(LineIcons.trash_o,
        size: 27,
      ),
      color: Colors.green[400],
    ),
```

Code below is in different widget from container code above.

```
RadioButtonGroup(
            labels: <String>[
              'Delete',
              'Archive',
              'Mark as read/unread',
              'Move to',
              'None'
            ],
            orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.VERTICAL,
            itemBuilder: (radio, text, index){
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  text, radio,
                ],
              );
              },
            onSelected: (selected){
              setState(() {
                rightSwipeSelected = selected;

              });
              },
            picked: rightSwipeSelected,
          ),
```

I need to have different colours for all different radiobuttons.

Comment: You must call setState() like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904495/how-to-change-a-text-style-on-flutter-when-button-pressed

Comment: Please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @codekls , please check the below updated solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @codekls, have you checked the below updated solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 1):

Here you go
Make sure install provider from https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-installing-tab-

Source Code on Github https://github.com/santoshanand/flutter-color-change-radio

Demo https://www.loom.com/share/7edc6d5d2d6e45d9addb59ce3a63fc72

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ChangeColorModel()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChangeColorModel with ChangeNotifier {
  RadioListValue _value = new RadioListValue(0, Colors.green[500], "Green");
  RadioListValue get currentValue => _value;

  void chageModel(RadioListValue m) {
    _value = m;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class RadioListValue {
  final int key;
  final Color color;
  final String label;
  RadioListValue(this.key, this.color, this.label);
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _buttonOptions = [
    RadioListValue(0, Colors.green[100], "Green"),
    RadioListValue(1, Colors.red, "Red"),
    RadioListValue(2, Colors.pink, "Pink"),
    RadioListValue(3, Colors.black38, "Black"),
    RadioListValue(4, Colors.yellow, "Yellow"),
    RadioListValue(5, Colors.brown, "Brown"),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home Page"),
      ),
      body: Consumer<ChangeColorModel>(builder: (context, model, _) {
        return Container(
          color: model.currentValue.color,
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: _buttonOptions
                .map(
                  (timeValue) => RadioListTile(
                    groupValue: model.currentValue.key,
                    title: Text(timeValue.label),
                    value: timeValue.key,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      model.chageModel(_buttonOptions[val]);
                    },
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for something like this but I have a kind of complicated problem for a newbie. The RadioButtons are in some Stateful widget and the container is in another widget. How do I link them both?

Comment: Something like changing the colors from settings page.

Comment: For that you need to use `Consumer<ChangeColorModel>(builder: (context, model, _) {}` in that class.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the color of the container just using `setState()` and use two variable for the color and selected checkbox position,In below code i have used the "1","2" and "3" String values for the selected `RadioListTile` for getting the value from it,please check the below cod for it

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {


  var selectedColor = Colors.grey;
  var selectedCheckBox = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Text(
            "HomeScreen",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          top: true,
          bottom: true,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
                  child: Icon(Icons.train,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                  color: selectedColor,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10.0,
                ),
                RadioListTile(
                  groupValue: selectedCheckBox == "" ? 0 :
                  selectedCheckBox == "1" ? true : false,
                  title: Text('Red'),
                  value: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedColor = Colors.red;
                      selectedCheckBox ="1";
                    });
                  },
                ),
                RadioListTile(
                  groupValue: selectedCheckBox == "" ? 0 :
                  selectedCheckBox == "2" ? true : false,
                  title: Text('Green'),
                  value: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedColor = Colors.green;
                      selectedCheckBox ="2";
                    });
                  },
                ), RadioListTile(
                  groupValue: selectedCheckBox == "" ? 0 :
                  selectedCheckBox == "3" ? true : false,
                  title: Text('Blue'),
                  value: true,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedColor = Colors.blue;
                      selectedCheckBox ="3";
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And output will be foloowing
[image]

Comment: I mentioned provider because radio buttons and container are in 2 different widgets.

Comment: Ok , Give me time , will do it in the morning

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with my actual code, I hope this clears the question better. I'm using ```grouped_buttons``` package for radiobuttons but I can use native syntax too if it's needed.

Comment: Ok give me sometime for it, will revert you today

Comment: @codekls One thing which I understand your requirement that you want to change the color of the RadioButtonGroup of selected radio button along with the container color

Comment: Not the RadioButtonGroup, if I select Delete I want it to be container (which is in other widget) to be red, if archive then colour should be yellow and so on. I'm still trying to understand state management.

Comment: Ok , means you want to change the color of both container and selected radio button