# Flutter change text and color

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[image]
Lists of color and names i want to build an app that will change color and text on tap. I want to change the container color and the text which are displayed on a list and randomize both of them. How can i do that?Here i want to change randomize both of them and get on tap
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please Share someCode

Comment: You can do that by searching this site for starters, there are plenty of questions around this like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904495/how-to-change-a-text-style-on-flutter-when-button-pressed

If you want more specific help, please post the code you have attempted and not homework style questions. Thanks!

Comment: i added, rewatch the post

Comment: @SabahatHussainQureshi here is the code

Answer (score 0):

this will give you random color

```
Color(0xFF000000+Random().nextInt(0xFFFFFF))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get random item from the list by using below code,

```
var randomName = names.elementAt(Random().nextInt(names.length)
```

use randomName and update in setState()

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name and color by tapping on the screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "dart:math";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: _title,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

List<String> names = [
  'John',
  'Maria',
  'Mike',
  'ABC',
  'ABCDEF',
  'XYZ',
  'ZXY',
];

List<Color> colors = [
  Colors.amber,
  Colors.grey,
  Colors.white,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.green,
];


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String? randomName;
  Color? randomColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final random = new Random();
    randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
    randomColor = colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
            randomColor = colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          color: randomColor, 
          child: Center(
            child: Text(randomName!),
          )
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But if i want to randomize them but the element from the list that was showed to be never used again?

Comment: It is random. Elements that have been randomly selected before may show up again.